# Relation between $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}(1+\tan x)^2dx$ and $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+x)^2(1+x^2)}dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let
> $$ \displaystyle I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1+\tan x)^2dx, \>\>\>\>\>
> \displaystyle I_2=\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2(1+x^2)}dx$$
>
> then find $\displaystyle\frac{I_1}{I_2}$

My method-

I was able to solve $I_1$ using standard formulae and got $I_1=1+\ln2$. Similarly, I solved for $I_2$ using partial fraction decomposition and got $I_2=0.25 (1+\ln 2)$. Therefore, the required ratio is $4$.

Is there some other way to solve this question?

Comment: Perhaps using the substitution $u=\tan x$ to convert $I_1$ into $\int_0^1\frac{(1+u)^2}{1+u^2}du$ could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note
\begin{align}
I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1+\tan x)^2dx
\overset{t=\tan x}= \int_0^{1}\frac{(1+t)^2}{1+t^2}dt
\overset{t\to \frac{1-t}{1+t}}=4I_2
\end{align}

Comment: Yours is the answer I was looking for, thankyou :-)

Comment: Two steps as one:  $x=\cot(t+\pi/4)$ yields $I_1 = 4 I_2$.

Comment: @GEdgar I think you have $t,\,x$ the wrong way round there, at least with respect to the use of $t$ in lieu of $x$ for $I_2$'s integration variable.

Comment: Correcting: two steps as one $t=\cot(x+\pi/4)$